# Jest open handle when using node exec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have this function that I'm using to invoke a commander script:

```
    function cli(args, cwd) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        exec(
        `node ${path.resolve("./index")} ${args.join(" ")}`,
        { cwd },
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            resolve({
            code: error && error.code ? error.code : 0,
            error,
            stdout,
            stderr
            });
        }
        );
    });
    }
```

On some invocations Jest logs the following:

```
    Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

    ●  PROCESSWRAP

        255 | function cli(args, cwd) {
        256 |   return new Promise(resolve => {
        > 257 |     exec(
            |     ^
        258 |       `node ${path.resolve("./index")} ${args.join(" ")}`,
        259 |       { cwd },
        260 |       (error, stdout, stderr) => {

        at exec (index.spec.js:257:5)
        at cli (index.spec.js:256:10)
        at Object.cli (index.spec.js:89:24)
```

Do I need to perform some type of finalization when using `exec` such that the handle is close?

For full context [this is the jest test script that contains the `cli` function](https://github.com/superflycss/cli/blob/master/index.spec.js).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm encountering the same problem and it seems like you should [`unref()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocessunref) the [ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesskillsignal). It seems like [`kill()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesskillsignal) sends a termination signal but the child process still communicates with the parent process so that communication is left over and jest is detecting that.

Not really sure if I'm understanding correctly how everything works but at least this fixed the issue for me:

```
// FIXES PIPEWRAP open handle
child_process.stdout.destroy()
child_process.stderr.destroy()
child_process.stdin.destroy()

// FIXES PROCESSWRAP open handle
child_process.kill() // (Optional: Just if you want to kill the process)
child_process.unref() // Necessary: fixes PROCESSWRAP
```